# Go to previous state in StateManager

Tags: ember.js

How can I "go back" to the last `currentState`? Does Ember provide a forward/backward implementation, something like `window.history.back()`?

Comment: When using a router your previous states are preserved in the `window.history`, so why not use `window.history.back()`?

Comment: just to be clear..its states or routes???

Comment: It's a state, or in other words, an `Ember.Route` without the `route` property, which would make a state in a non-url-environment using a plain `StateManager`.

Comment: I don't think `Ember.StateManager` or `Ember.State` offer a functionality for that, but even if you implement some type of "state bag", you have to take into account the objects that would be potentially affected by the application in the current (or any other) state. Say you're state A and you transition to B and the model is common for both, then on B you change the model and commit the change, what do you expect to happen when you transition back to A?

Comment: You're right, it seems like I'll have to find another way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The back/forward button on the browser will update URLs which will trigger router to transition. When this occurs, a `navigateAway` event will be sent to the current Route, so you have a chance to do whatever clean up may be necessary.

BTW, if you think through this problem, you will realize that the user could tap a bookmarklet or manually update the URL at any time, which means you could be transitioning from any route to any other route in your app. That's a nasty combinatorial problem, and probably one that is not worth solving for most apps.

Comment: Thanks, Luke. I think it doesn't make sense to go back and forward, because, as MilkyWayJoe said, objects might be affected...